# GoDaddy .htaccess issues - simple fix

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I purchased a script from codecanyon and have installed everything else without hassle however the problem is I keep getting a 404 error due to what I think is a .htaccess issue. I've had similar scripts on this same server and it has always come down to it being resolved by tweaking the .htaccess.

Would anyone have any suggestions on what to change as this is currently not working:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^category/(.*)/(.*)$ category.php?id=$1&slug=$2
RewriteRule ^source/(.*)/(.*)$ source.php?id=$1&slug=$2
RewriteRule ^news/(.*)/(.*)$ news.php?id=$1&slug=$2
RewriteRule ^page/(.*)/(.*)$ page.php?id=$1&slug=$2
RewriteRule ^search/(.*)$ search.php?q=$1
RewriteRule ^not-found$ notfound.php
RewriteRule ^rss.xml$ rss.php
RewriteRule ^sitemap-(.*).xml$ sitemap.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^categories-sitemap.xml$ categories-sitemap.php
```

So I added this

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes
```

And now my .htaccess: file looks like below but still does not work.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^category/(.*)/(.*)$ category.php?id=$1&slug=$2
RewriteRule ^source/(.*)/(.*)$ source.php?id=$1&slug=$2
RewriteRule ^news/(.*)/(.*)$ news.php?id=$1&slug=$2
RewriteRule ^page/(.*)/(.*)$ page.php?id=$1&slug=$2
RewriteRule ^search/(.*)$ search.php?q=$1
RewriteRule ^not-found$ notfound.php
RewriteRule ^rss.xml$ rss.php
RewriteRule ^sitemap-(.*).xml$ sitemap.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^categories-sitemap.xml$ categories-sitemap.php
```

I gave up and am seeking help. When I try going to a link without the .htaccess rewrite my post shows up

for example this does not work:
http://rockwallhistoricsquare.com/news/20/stand-off-in-rockwall

yet, this does works:
 http://www.rockwallhistoricsquare.com/news.php?id=20&slug=stand-off-in-rockwall

What am I doing wrong? Help is much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Also, what file permissions should .htaccess have? I accidentally set everything to 777 so if that's an issue I can change that right away...

Comment: After trying it myself, your rewrite rules appear to work just fine. If you have access to an apache error log (you might not with GoDaddy) check that - it will tell you what apache tried (and failed) to serve. If that doesn't give you enough clues to solve it, update the question with the log and we can help more.

Comment: Hey @HPierce thanks for trying. Well I the error Logs will be available until 
Monday, October 12, 2015 2:27:55 PM... so no access there. The code developer is checking on the script on my server and if he finds anything out I will post problem is this developer has been know to take months just to answer ugh.

Comment: he couldn't figure it out either... :(

Comment: This worked:DirectoryIndex index.php
AddDefaultCharset utf-8

RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews -Indexes   

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^category/(.*)/(.*)$ category.php?id=$1&slug=$2
RewriteRule ^source/(.*)/(.*)$ source.php?id=$1&slug=$2
RewriteRule ^news/(.*)/(.*)$ news.php?id=$1&slug=$2
RewriteRule ^page/(.*)/(.*)$ page.php?id=$1&slug=$2
RewriteRule ^search/(.*)$ search.php?q=$1
RewriteRule ^not-found$ notfound.php
RewriteRule ^rss.xml$ rss.php
RewriteRule ^sitemap-(.*).xml$ sitemap.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^categories-sitemap.xml$ categories-sitemap.php

Answer (score 0):

```
DirectoryIndex index.php<br>
AddDefaultCharset utf-8<br>
RewriteEngine on<br>
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews -Indexes
RewriteRule ^category/(.*)/(.*)$ category.php?id=$1&slug=$2
RewriteRule ^source/(.*)/(.*)$ source.php?id=$1&slug=$2
RewriteRule ^news/(.*)/(.*)$ news.php?id=$1&slug=$2
RewriteRule ^page/(.*)/(.*)$ page.php?id=$1&slug=$2
RewriteRule ^search/(.*)$ search.php?q=$1
RewriteRule ^not-found$ notfound.php
RewriteRule ^rss.xml$ rss.php
RewriteRule ^sitemap-(.*).xml$ sitemap.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^categories-sitemap.xml$ categories-sitemap.php
```

This Works Very Well